# Saving Binary inside an Array

Tags: windows

I'm doing a program where I have to convert an ASCII code into binary and then pass it into an array, like

```
int[] c = { 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
```

Now I have written the program to convert ASCII into binary

using the following code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string str1;

    str1 = textBox1.Text.ToString();
    ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] bytes = ascii.GetBytes(str1);
    string result ="";
    foreach (byte b in bytes)
        result += Convert.ToString(b, 2);
    //MessageBox.Show(result);
    string str2;
    str2 = result.ToString();
    textBox2.Text = str2;


}
```

Now suppose I give the value 'A' it gets converted into `1100001`, I want to convert it into values `1,1,0,0,0,0,1`, and pass it into the above mentioned `int[] c;`.

Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the class [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx), perhaps it fits your needs

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(ascii.GetBytes(str1));
```

The BitArray already represents an array of booleans.

To convert it to an array of integers, if this is really needed for a following use, you can loop though it:

```
int[] intArray = new int[bits.Length];
for(int i = 0; i<bits.Length; i++)
    intArray[i] = bits[i] ? 1 : 0;
```

or any other loop of your choice

Comment: i used BitArray as recommended by you.

Comment: can you provide more clarity to use it. i get error as invalid cating error